# Dynamic "column" update in mysql with respect to parameter of procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update a column of my table `T1` in a procedure called `my_proc(param)`.
I want to do something like this:

```
if param=1 then UPDATE T1 SET C1="SOME VALUE"
if param=2 then UPDATE T1 SET C2="SOME VALUE"
if param=3 then UPDATE T1 SET C3="SOME VALUE"
...
```

Cnn anyone suggest, what should be an appropriate approach?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is basically right.  The correct syntax is:

```
if param = 1 then
    UPDATE T1
        SET C1 = 'SOME VALUE';
elseif param = 2 then
   UPDATE T1
       SET C2 = 'SOME VALUE';
elseif param = 3 then
    UPDATE T1
        SET C3 = 'SOME VALUE'
end if;
```

If you like, you could write this as one `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET C1 = (case when param = 1 then 'SOME VALUE' else C1 end),
        C2 = (case when param = 2 then 'SOME VALUE' else C2 end),
        C3 = (case when param = 3 then 'SOME VALUE' else C3 end);
```

Comment: My mistake,I should add a bit more information in my question. That is numbers upon 'C' depends on 'param'. Likewise 'param' will be appended with 'C'. This is the main problems I asked to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @query = CONCAT("update t1 set c", @param ,"=?");
SET @val = 'somevalue';
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt USING @val;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Use dynamic sql for this